# Set variable to array element

Tags: php, arrays

I need to set a variable = to an array element. $var = $ary[1]; does not work. ary[1]= "test". If that helps

Comment: You might need to be more specific about what you're trying to do and the results of what you've tried. `$var = $ary[1]` is certainly a valid assignment.

Comment: hello Dan first echo $ary[1] and see that it is having the value?

Comment: Since you are new to stackoverflow, if charlie answered your code correctly please select it as the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

PHP arrays are zero indexed, that may be your problem

```
    $ary = array("test");
    $var = $ary[0]
```

$var == "test"

Comment: how to use it for `$content = array( "en" => $massage ); `

Answer (score 2):

confirm that your first initialize the array variable before using it like:

```
$ary=array();
```

Try this:

```
$ary[]= $var;
```

must use `$` sign for var/arrays in php and you don't require 1 if a single value is inserted..

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to set a variable with array elemen.

why it is not working , please check your array content .

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$content = array( "en" => "{$massage}" );
```